# AngularJS: HTML Table with contenteditable and validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an HTML table as below:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <th>User Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in respose">
        <td contenteditable="true">{{item.userId}}</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">{{item.name}}</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">{{item.address}}</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

I am using the following contenteditable directive:

```
app.directive('contenteditable', ['$sce', function($sce) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
    require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
    }
  };
}]);
```

The setup can be seen as: http://jsfiddle.net/cazfs31L/

Since the cells of the table are editable, I want to add validation to these cells to restrict the data that is being entered to them. The tricky part being I want to add validation based on the column header if possible. E.g. if the header is "Name" add different validation as compared to "Id" header/column.

I am just showing 3 columns in my demo but there can be more columns and more rows. Also, I don't want to use a textbox instead of cells here.

Any ideas how can I add validation here?

Comment: just add another attribute `<td contenteditable="true" row="{{$index}}"` and read it in directive from $attrs

Comment: i used a row, but the same for column

Comment: @llia would you be able to give me an example, I am not sure about what you posted above.

Comment: so, this is your td `<td contenteditable="true" data-column="0">{{item.userId}}</td>`, inside directive you can access to data-column via attrs `link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {      
      console.log(attrs.column);
    }`

Comment: @llia with your code I can get the column name in the directive, see my updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aman1981/4p125zmt/5/  How can add validation to the rows now? My questions was to look at the column header and then apply validation to the rows accordingly for that column.

Comment: how the validation supposed to work?

Comment: Its based on the column. For ex: if the column name is "userid" then  no numbers allowed. If the column is "name" no numbers or spl chars allowed. I should be able to adjust the validation. Just need headsup on how to setup the validation based on column and apply to row.

Comment: data-column should be added on td, not on th

Comment: then you can use 'keypress' event to handle user's action on element, ie `element.on('keypress', (e) => {if (attrs.column === '') e.preventDefault()); }`

Comment: Thanks. I got it now.  See my updated JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aman1981/4p125zmt/31/  Any better way to apply regex or this is fine?

Comment: regex is ok, you can make bit simpler `/^[A-z]$/`

Comment: [`[A-z]` also matches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970) some non-letters.